# Wordpress blog set up

Tags: php, blog, include

I plan to launch my website with multiple blogs plugged into it, with a main index page for all posts.

I currently have the index running from the root and two blogs running within their own folders from the root, each with Wordpress installed and running underneath. I have set the database so that the 2 blogs are storing data in the same database with the table prefixes separating out the data. ie. in howard_database, there are tables with blog1_ and blog2_ as their prefixes. (I realise this might not be the cleanest way to do it but I like each blog having its own separate login, as oppose to each being in the same Wordpress installation and separated out by tag/category.)

Is there a way that I can show all blog posts from each blog on the index page as a summary of all my posts if the root doesn't have a wordpress installation?

Also, I obviously want a theme running through the entire site, and have created a few php includes in a folder on the root. The problem I have is I cannot seem to link back to them from the wordpress blog installation folders to include them within the individual blog pages.

Thanks

Comment: This question reads like a *work for me for free* type of question. It is overly broad, appears to encompass multiple questions, and is written fairly vaguely. Can you please edit your question to better clarify the scope and exact nature of what you are asking?

Comment: I was looking for an overall opinion of how best to set up a summary page of blogs (when the summary page itself is not set up with an installation of Wordpress) and how a theme could be well established and used throughout said system. I don't see how I could have gone more into depth.

(and, there's no mention or want for someone to do it all for me)

Comment: "*I was looking for an overall opinion of...*" - I appreciate that; however, WPSE is a **Question and Answer** site. Questions that solicit opinion or extended discussion are not a good fit for the WPSE format. That's why I asked if you could tighten the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be looking into [WordPress multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite). Multisite is a way to run multiple sites on a single installation of WordPress. WordPress.com is an example. One big advantage of multisite is that it runs off a single set of plugins and themes. That means you can allow separate users/authors to only have access to certain sites while still only having to keep one site updated.

Also, with multisite, you're going to have an easier time sharing blog posts. Here's one [tutorial](http://wpmu.org/daily-tip-share-posts-across-a-wordpress-multisite-network/). There are also some multisite specific plugins that offer similar functionality.

Finally, I should add that at the beginning of your post, it did sound like categorizing was your best solution. If you really want the separate user permissions, multisite may be the way to go, but I'd encourage you to read "[Don't Use WordPress Multisite](http://halfelf.org/2011/dont-use-wordpress-multisite/)" for a great list of reasons to NOT use multisite. There's nothing wrong with using it, but you want to make sure your choice to do so is an informed decision.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer. I will look into the possibilities of using multisite.